# Find Closest Index in line string to insert new vertex using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I want to find the index from Line String to insert new vertex on it.

I am using ST_Add Point function but it requires specified index for inserting vertex.How to get those index based on given input points from line string.

**My Input Line String:**
"LINE STRING Z (496328.772173402 4622876.01448448 208.4005,496327.883130287 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496494.578714408 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496497.898850613 4622875.89518039 208.4005)"

**My Input Point:**
'POINT Z(496458.12794668 4622814.67050952 208.4005)'

**Expected Output:**
"LINE STRING Z (496328.772173402 4622876.01448448 208.4005,496327.883130287 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496458.12794668 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496494.578714408 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496497.898850613 4622875.89518039 208.4005)"

I need to insert on 3rd position on given line string. But i am not able to
find the exact segment index for inserting new point.

I am using following query with manual index 2.But i need to get index automatically

```
update public.linetype
set geom=ST_AddPoint(geom,  ST_Make Point(496458.12794668 4622814.67050952 208.4005),2) where id=4
from public.linetype
```

public.linetype is my table name and geom is linestring geometry column.

PostGIS Version 2.4.4 and PostgreSQL 10.4

Comment: if your point is always on the linestring, you can use this [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40622/how-to-add-vertices-to-existing-linestrings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this in PostGIS currently.  See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368483/14766) for a possible solution.

UPDATE: You can use [`ST_Snap`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_Snap.html) to do the point insertion in one step:

```
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_Snap( 
  'LINESTRING Z (496328.772173402 4622876.01448448 208.4005,496327.883130287 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496494.578714408 4622814.67050952 208.4005,496497.898850613 4622875.89518039 208.4005)',
  'POINT Z(496458.12794668 4622814.67050952 208.4005)',
  0.1
));
```